# sql for update table from other table with each table have condition, not working

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update, db2-400

First of all I am not very well versed in DB2 SQL.

I have A TABLE and TABLE B. A TABLE contains the last modification data, while TABLE B contains data history / track record from table TABLE A.

I want to update column **TABLEA.LAST_PRICE** (with conditions DEAL_DATE = '1753-01-01' and CODE <> '') filled with **TABLEB.LAST_PRICE** (with the condition DEAL_DATE <> '1753-01-01' and CODE <> '' and order by CHANGE_DATE desc limit 1) where the **foreign key for the two tables is TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID**

- Table A can be seen here:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE6NB.jpg)
- Table B can be seen here: [enter    link description here](http://paste.masterweb.com/show.php?id=191183)

I have tried updating the TABLEA with the following 3 SQLs, **but never succeeded:**

```
 1. update DB.TABLEA as a set a.LAST_PRICE = (select LAST_PRICE from
    DB.TABLEB as b where b.DEAL_DATE <> '1753-01-01' and a.ID = b.ID and
    b.CODE <> '' order by b.CHANGE_DATE desc FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)
    where a.DEAL_DATE = '1753-01-01' and a.CODE <>  '' ;




2.  update DB.TABLEA as a set a.LAST_PRICE = (select LAST_PRICE from
    DB.TABLEB as b where b.DEAL_DATE <> '1753-01-01' and a.ID = b.ID and
    b.CODE <> '' order by b.CHANGE_DATE desc limit 1) where a.DEAL_DATE = '1753-01-01' and a.CODE <>  '' ;




3. update DB.TABLEA set a.LAST_PRICE = b.LAST_PRICE from DB.TABLEA  a
    join DB.TABLEB  b on a.ID = b.ID where a.DEAL_DATE = '1753-01-01'
    and a.CODE <> '' and b.DEAL_DATE <> '1753-01-01' and b.CODE <> ''
    order by b.CHANGE_DATE desc FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

I'm getting crazy with this query.
Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: If TABLEA and TABLEB are in diffent DB you can update or insert. Only select work remotly on DB2.

Comment: Please, create a reproducible example including the following statements for both tables: table definition (`CREATE TABLE`), `INSERT INTO` statements with a 2-3 rows for some particular ID.

Comment: Hi Nifriz, thank before for reply.
TABLEA and TABLEB are in the same database. i want update TABLEA for record take it from TABLEB. but about the three my sql  not working.

Comment: Do you receive a SQLSTATE/SQLCODE Error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dates aren't converting properly. The optimizer might be converting your TABLEB DEAL_DATE to a timestamp then a character which wouldn't match the purely character string. When making comparisons of dates it is usually best to have them compared as actual dates and not just representations of them.

```
update DB.TABLEA as a set a.LAST_PRICE = (select LAST_PRICE from
    DB.TABLEB as b where cast(b.DEAL_DATE as date) <> cast('1753-01-01' as date) and a.ID = b.ID and
    b.CODE <> '' order by b.CHANGE_DATE desc FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)
    where cast(a.DEAL_DATE as date) = cast('1753-01-01' as date) and a.CODE <>  '' ;
```